# Transferring website from server to localhost using WAMP

Tags: magento-1.8, database, core, localhost, wamp

I'm trying to transfer live website to me localhost.

Steps I did:
 1. Made folder in wamp/www
 2. Copied FTP files there
 3. Imported database
 4. Changed core_config_data for unsucure/base url and sucure/base url to `http://localhost/FolderImade`
 5. Deleted everything in var folder
 6. Updated database host, name and password in etc/local.xml

This is the result I'm getting with console feed:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhY3T.jpg

So far I have tried suggestions I've found in different threads for example:

```
UPDATE cms_block SET cms_block.content = REPLACE (cms_block.content, 'sitename.com', 'sitename.dev');
UPDATE cms_page SET cms_page.content = REPLACE (cms_page.content, 'sitename.com','sitename.dev');
```

And

```
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_export ; 
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_import ; 
TRUNCATE log_customer ; 
TRUNCATE log_quote ; 
TRUNCATE log_summary ; 
TRUNCATE log_summary_type ; 
TRUNCATE log_url ; 
TRUNCATE log_url_info ; 
TRUNCATE log_visitor ; 
TRUNCATE log_visitor_info ; 
TRUNCATE log_visitor_online ; 
TRUNCATE report_event ;
```

And

```
ALTER TABLE `log_visitor_info` CHANGE `visitor_id` `visitor_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Visitor ID';
```

And

```
If you are using apache rewrites and not storing your site in the root web directory (i.e. you are storing it at localhost/foo, make sure you have the line RewriteBase /foo/ present and uncommented in .htaccess
```

Also I've tried some other stuff I found in various threads.For additional info I'm using windows 7. Magento ver. 1.8.1.0    Does anyone have any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Have you got solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `base_url` is not set correctly. Try this query on your DB

`UPDATE core_config_data SET value = REPLACE(value, 'sitename.com','sitename.dev');`

If that doesn't work, take a look at what your `base_url` and other URLs are set as, and make adjustments as necessary.

`SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE PATH LIKE "%url%";`

Comment: Thanks for you help, I have tried both of your suggestions but none worked unfortunately.

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the output of this query: `SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE PATH LIKE "%url%";`